# Debug .NET Framework's source code only shows disassembly in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, debugging

I'm trying to debug .NET Framework's source code using [Visual Studio 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) Professional. I followed the steps described in [Raj Kaimal](https://web.archive.org/web/20130910224231/http://weblogs.asp.net:80/rajbk/archive/2010/04/21/setting-up-visual-studio-2010-to-step-into-microsoft-net-source-code.aspx)'s post, but I must be doing something wrong since the only code I'm getting to see is the disassembly code:

[image]
<sub>(source: [github.com](http://jdecuyper.github.com/images/SO/vs2010DebugFramework.jpg))</sub>

As you can see in the image, the *Go to Source Code* and the *Load Symbols* options are disabled. Nevertheless, symbols are downloaded from Microsoft's server since I can see them inside the local cache directory.

The code I'm debugging goes as follow:

```
var wr = WebRequest.Create("http://www.google.com");
Console.WriteLine("Web request created");
var req = wr.GetRequestStream();
Console.Read();
```

When I hit <kbd>F11</kbd> to step into the first line of code, a window pops us looking for the "WebRequst.cs" file inside "f:\dd\ndp\fx\src\Net\System\Net\WebRequest.cs" which does not exists on my machine.

What am I missing?

Comment: jdecuyper, have you resolved the issue? I am interesting in this also. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In project properties, target .NET Framework 4.0. I had the same issue when I was compiling for .NET 3.5.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but targeting the .NET 4 client profile. Switching to the full framework 4 did not help.

Comment: Using 4.7.1 I have the problem