# "Source information is missing from the debug information for this module" when debugging asp.net mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdb-files

I am having hard days of debugging ASP.NET MVC code.I ended up doing as described in this [website](https://www.symbolsource.org/Public/Wiki/Using).Debug symbols are loaded and working for all dlls but `System.Web.MVC`. when i double click on any line in `stacktrace` window it show me the message `Source information is missing from the debug information for this module`.i use `http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols` as symbol source.what am i missing?is my symbol server correct?

Comment: Hi sir, any luck afterward? I get the exact same error message and did similar thing

Comment: No i couldn't make it working but I've found an alternative to visual studio debugger and forgot about debugging closes sourced library with VS.since then i am debugging with dnSpy  an opensource .net debugger which support .net core as well.check this https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy

Comment: I just get it to work yesterday. switch to 5.2.7 does the trick for me. for some reason, 5.2.4 just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I can successfully debug asp.net MVC 5.2.7 source code.

1. Please download MVC 5.2.7 package here:
   https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/aspnetwebstack-dev/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
2. Download the corresponding source code here (remember to switch to the correct branch):
   https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack
3. Set up your symbol server according to [symbol server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903669/debugging-asp-net-mvc-5-2-3-source-code)
4. During debugging, make sure the dll is loaded.